# ことになった vs ことになっている

Tags: nuances

So I get the general gist that ことになりました means 'its has been decided that~'

For example:

> 私は来年大阪に転勤することになりました。

And that ことになっています essential means the same thing, but indicates that the decision took place at sometime in the past and the result of that is still in effect.

For example:

> 日本では車は道の左側を走ることになっています。

But even so, I can't get in my mind around the slight difference in meaning between:

> 今日山田先生に会うことになっています。
>
> 今日山田先生に会うことになりました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in meaning is rather simple.

「ことになりました」 means that the decision/plan/rule has just been made.  It may have been just a few seconds ago or a few days ago.  Point is the news is still new to the speaker.

「ことになっています」 means that the decision/plan/rule was made some time (or a long time) ago.  The news is no longer new to the speaker and s/he is more "ready" for the event.

Comment: Why is it that "becoming" implies a longer period of time ago than "become"?